# An exam question about digraph and adjacency matrix

Tags: graph-theory

I have an exam question, but I could not understand properly and solve it ;;  Using the adjacency matrix V of a digraph G, how do you determine the set of predecessors of a given node u? Determine the time complexity of this operation.

Comment: Have you tried this at all? Remember the adjacency matrix tells you what edges go to what nodes and in what order, so you should just have to check the entriy $a_{ij}$ to see if it is equal to $0$ or not.

Comment: OK so for example I will see B node can reach to A , so I can show C is one of predecessors of A , if I find B node in adjacency list of C .  How can I describe the complexity , probably I will check all nodes and edges , O(V+E) can be the complexity ?

Comment: If the node is $i$ then we look in the $i$-th row (well maybe column because I never know in what direction they are normally written). Each column that has a $1$ in the $i$-th row will be a(n inmediate) predecessor of $i$. This search costs $n$. For each collumn $i_2$ that had a one, we look at row $i_2$ and repeat searching for all the columns that have a $1$ in that row. You can see that the max cost could be $n^2$.

Comment: Does Predecessor means that if I can reach A node from B using only one edge ( or a path with lenght 1) then A is predecessor of B ? , or I can say predecessor if I can reach A node from B using a path with length 2 or more? . I may need to find power of the matrix.